# How to stop the Bottle webserver when started from subprocess

Tags: python, windows, console-application, subprocess, bottle

I would like to embed the great [Bottle](http://bottle.paws.de/) web framework into a small application (1st target is Windows OS). This app starts the bottle webserver thanks to the subprocess module.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('python websrv.py')
```

The bottle app is quite simple

```
@route("/")
def index():
    return template('index')

run(reloader=True)
```

It starts the default webserver into a Windows console.

All seems Ok except the fact that I must press Ctrl-C to close the bottle webserver. I would like that the master app terminates the webserver when it shutdowns. I can't find a way to do that (p.terminate() doesn't work in this case unfortunately)

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If still interested, you may find useful my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282218/bottle-web-framework-how-to-stop/16056443#16056443

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to shutdown a reloading server:

1) You terminate p (using `os.kill(p.pid)` or `p.terminate()` ) and then change the modification time of 'websrv.py' (`os.utime('websrv.py')`) to trigger an automatic shutdown of the child process.

2) You terminate p with `os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)` which is identical to a `Ctrl-C` shutdown.

Comment: Does 2) work on Windows? Thanks for the answer. I will try that.

Comment: If signal.SIGINT is defined, this should work on windows, too. I haven't tested it, though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the terminate process doesn't work if Bottle is in reload mode. In this case, it starts iteself a subprocess.

If reload is set to False, the terminate seems to work Ok.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with 0.8.1 the reloading server is smart enough to clean up orphan processes. You now have several ways to terminate the server:

- Hit `Ctrl-C` or send `SIGINT` to the parent process. (recommended)
- Kill the parent process. The child will die gracefully within 2 seconds.
- Kill the child process or sys.exit() with any status code other than 3. The parent will die immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble closing a bottle server from within a request as bottle seems to run requests in subprocesses.

I eventually found the solution was to do:

```
sys.stderr.close()
```

inside the request (that got passed up to the bottle server and axed it).

Maybe try doing that in your process and see if bottle gets the message.