# how to shut down python bottle paste server by demand?

Tags: python, bottle

I'm using python bottle framework with paste as the web server.
Here is my initialization code:

```
bottle.run(port=os.getenv('SERVER_PORT'), host=os.getenv('SERVER_HOST'), server='paste')
```

I want to shutdown the bottle server by command by sending a request:

```
@bottle.get("/suicide")
def KilleMe():
pass
```

I have no idea what to write in the function body.
Please help!

p.s: I saw some answers ([some anwer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282218/bottle-web-framework-how-to-stop/16056443#16056443) but wasn't able to combine them in my code....

Comment: can you use `exit()` or do you want it to do something else?

Comment: no good. python bottle does not shut down when doing that

Comment: What was wrong with the `stop` function?

Comment: can you suggest how to use it in the function body. thanks

Comment: @JFA How to use the `stop` function from inside a route `@bottle.route("/stop")`? Can you post an answer with this? Thanks in advance.