# Restart Bottle app (programmatically)

Tags: python, database-connection, bottle, restart, peewee

How do I restart my Bottle app programmatically?

```
def error_handler(error):
    if error.message == "connection already closed":
        RESTART_BOTTLE_SERVER()  # This will reacquire connection
```

Comment: Just after quick look - probably you just need to use threads?(Maybe I get it wrong, sorry for off topic then)

Comment: My restart what do you want to do go to the starting page or refresh the page or start again from beginning

Comment: It depends on the server you're using--not on Bottle per se.  But I'm suspicious that perhaps you haven't thought this through completely.  For example: what happens to the request that caused the error; it's still processing.  And what happens to all the other requests bottle is handling?

Comment: You can stop the bottle framework using the approach in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282218/bottle-web-framework-how-to-stop/16056443#16056443

Comment: Hmm, that might be the solution I was seeking. Write it up into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the bottle app (thread) with the approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282218/bottle-web-framework-how-to-stop/16056443#16056443).

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommed you'll run your bottle server as a daemon in the background on your OS. You can than start and stop your server and use simple python code to kill the thread. [BottleDaemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BottleDaemon/0.1.0) might do the job for you.

```
from bottledaemon import daemon_run
from bottle import route

@route("/hello")
def hello():
  return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  daemon_run()
```

The above application will launch in the background. This top-level script can be used to start/stop the background process easily:

```
jonathans-air:bottle-daemon jhood$ python bottledaemon/bottledaemon.py
usage: bottledaemon.py [-h] {start,stop}
```

Now you can use bottledaemon.py to start or stop or restart your application and call it from your main python file.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to use the init system (systemd, upstart or regular init scripts) to keep it always running.